# R Converting Matrix with Row Names in to a Dataframe where the Row Names are individual variables

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

If I have a matrix with row names such as

```
data<-matrix(1:9, nrow =3, ncol = 3)
fake.names <- c('Abby', 'Bobby', 'Cindy')
rownames(data)<-fake.names
print(data)
    #[,1] [,2] [,3]
    # Abby     1    4    7
    # Bobby    2    5    8
    # Cindy    3    6    9
```

How can I convert it to a dataframe where the names are variables such as:

```
# df.names df.numbers
# 1     Abby          1
# 2     Abby          4
# 3     Abby          7
# 4    Bobby          2
# 5    Bobby          5
# 6    Bobby          8
# 7    Cindy          3
# 8    Cindy          6
# 9    Cindy          9
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
data <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
fake.names <- c("Abby", "Bobby", "Cindy")
rownames(data) <- fake.names

data.frame(
  df.names = rownames(data),
  df.numbers = c(data)
)
#>   df.names df.numbers
#> 1     Abby          1
#> 2    Bobby          2
#> 3    Cindy          3
#> 4     Abby          4
#> 5    Bobby          5
#> 6    Cindy          6
#> 7     Abby          7
#> 8    Bobby          8
#> 9    Cindy          9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Get the `t`ranspose, convert to `data.frame` and `stack` it to two column data.frame

```
stack(as.data.frame(t(data)))[2:1]
```

-output

```
     ind values
1  Abby      1
2  Abby      4
3  Abby      7
4 Bobby      2
5 Bobby      5
6 Bobby      8
7 Cindy      3
8 Cindy      6
9 Cindy      9
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
data.frame(
  names = row.names(data)[t(row(data))], 
  numbers = c(t(data))
)
```

which gives

```
  names numbers
1  Abby       1
2  Abby       4
3  Abby       7
4 Bobby       2
5 Bobby       5
6 Bobby       8
7 Cindy       3
8 Cindy       6
9 Cindy       9
```